# livefyre npm in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, livefyre

I'm trying to make a package to get the livefyre npm module installed in meteor (a client has requested I try and use it).

I've followed the information [here](https://coderwall.com/p/srvdta) but am getting errors saying `Errors while scanning packages: File not found: livefyre.js` when I run meteor add livefyre

I've made a packages/livefyre directory under my project root and it it have package.js

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "livefyre package"
});

Npm.depends({
  'livefyre':'1.1.4'
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('livefyre.js', 'client');
});
```

and another file called livefyre_settings.js with

```
liveFyre = Npm.require("livefyre");
```

and that's it so far.

The npm package seems to be installed, I can see it under `/home/pnunn/.npm/livefyre/1.1.4/package/lib/livefyre.js`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, these instructions [here](http://tech.exponential.io/meteor/npm-module-meteor-package/) atleast got it installed (not sure if it should be in client or server though). Now just need to make it work...

I should have been loading a file in my directory structure, not livefyre.js from the npm package as I thought I was doing. This then includes the package one.

Peter.